# When is "been" pronounced /biːn/ rather than /bɪn/?

Tags: british-english

The OALD reports two pronunciations for *been*, used in British English:

- /biːn/
- /bɪn/

The latter is the same pronunciation reported for North American English.

When is *been* pronounced in a way, rather than the other one? Is it just a matter of the position of the word in the sentence?

Comment: /biːn/ is British strong form of the word, pronounced when the word is stressed. /bɪn/ is the weak form.

Comment: I'm not great with the pronunciation symbols; are we talking "bean" vs "bin"?

Comment: @WendiKidd Nope. It's _been_, the past participle of _be_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Whoops, my mistake, I should have been clearer. That was me attempting to sound-spell the different pronunciations of "been" to make sure I understood what you were asking. Having failed, I shall leave this to those who know better than I ;) Have a +1! :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Oh. `:)` Yes, the first pronunciation I have written is also the pronunciation of _bean_. This reminds me of [Young Frankenstein](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072431/quotes?item=qt0484647) movie: "You must be Igor." "No, it's pronounced 'eye-gor.'"

Comment: @Fantaiser Post that as an Answer, maybe with a citation or so, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: It can even be pronounced as "ben" to rhyme with "pen". Source: Merriam-Webster's Dictionary.

Comment: @stillenat: I assume the people who do that are the ones who pronounce "pin" and "pen" the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/biːn/ is British strong form of *'been'*, pronounced when the word is stressed. /bɪn/ is the weak form, whose vowel – /ɪ/ – is reduced from /iː/ Similar phenomena happen with other words, especially with pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions, articles, and auxiliary verbs: 'a' (/eɪ/ => /ə/), 'she' (/ʃiː/ => /ʃi/), and 'would' (/wʊd/ => /wəd/, /əd/) etc.

These are because when people actually speak, these kinds of words are with other more important words which carry the stress.

#### Source

- [Stress and vowel reduction in English / Weak and strong forms of function words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Weak_and_strong_forms_of_function_words)
- [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/)
- Michael Swan (2005). *Practical English Usage.* Oxford: OUP.

Answer (score 1):

So it actually helps to be aware of language history. Obviously American English comes from England, but why do the two sound so different?  Well, one of them changed over time, and it's probably not the one you think.
The American English accent is actually what was spoken back in the 17th century and before in England, and the British English accent changed after the American colonies were well established.
In short, the [bɪn] or [bɛn] (bin) pronunciations were first, as attested in old dictionaries and poems (by comparing rhyming words). It wasn't until the mid 19th century that British English speakers began using the [bi:n] (bean) pronunciation in order to have it fit more with the spelling (From "English Spelling and Spelling Reform", Thomas R. Lounsbury (1909)).

I realize this is an old question, but I hope anyone else looking up the answer to this question finds this helpful!

Comment: this isn't even close to true. Both accents have change vastly.  American English has changed massively in the last half century, let alone 400 years

Answer (score -2):

The word *been* is normally pronounced the same as the word *bean*. Pronouncing it as *bin* the same way as the word for a container for waste http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bin_1?q=bin , is a weak pronunciation and something colloquial. There is no particular rule about it. It is just a personal thing that some people do.